# Summing a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've found one strange thing in Python 3.6. Following code returns

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(sum([[i] for i in arr]))
```

Why does it happen? How can I summarize a list of lists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the help from the REPL:

```
>>> help(sum)
```

---

```
sum(iterable, start=0, /)
    Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

    When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
    This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
    reject non-numeric types.
```

So, the `sum` built-in returns the sum of the `start` value, i.e. `0`, and an iterable of *numbers*. Python doesn't prevent you from misusing a function beforehand, it trusts that you are at least trying to do the right thing. Of course, if you happen to pass a list-of-lists, the first list element will be summed with `0`, raising:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Indeed, if you pass a `start` argument, an empty list, in this case, it works:

```
>>> sum([[e] for e in x], [])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

However, this will be inefficient. You should prefer `[x for sublist in list_of_lists for x in sublist]` or any other linear time algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `[[i] for i in arr]` returns `[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]`.

Why not just simply print the sum of the array:

```
print(sum(arr))
```

Or, if you don't want to change your `[[i] for i in arr]`:

```
print(sum([[i] for i in arr], []))
```

I prefer using `sum(arr)` though, shorter code and readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it this way.

```
print (sum(i for i in arr))
```

If you use parenthesis around 'i' like [i], this means 'i' is a element in a tuple, and you can't possibly add a integer, with a list.

**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' -->** It means it cannot add integer with a list. Because when you use a for loop, it gives you a single element each time, the loop is executed i.e., an integer, but you are expecting a list to be returned to sum() function. Therefore it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score -1):

Just do...

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print sum(arr)
```

You want to **sum** multiple elements. You already have a list to input to function. Why would you want a list comprehension, using the list you already have ?

If you want to **flatten** a list of list into a single list, in order to **sum** it all, you could watch this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python/952952#952952), and use **sum** as I did above.