# Why can't I sum lists with in-built sum?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If you have

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
y = ['D', 'E', 'F']
```

then you can calculate:

```
x+y # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

But if you do

```
sum([x,y])
```

you get

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Any idea why?

Comment: Sure, [Summing a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536659/summing-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 6):

Its, because `sum` allways 'adds' the `start` element which defaults to `0`.
Try

```
sum([x,y], start=[])
```